# What are some of the influences on Judaism post Constantine The Great?

Tags: history, christianity, secular-culture

Up until Constantine The Great both Jewish and Christian religions were small religions among many others that vanished throughout history. Not only they were small, but both were also constantly persecuted.

When Constantine The Great had his “revelation”, he forcefully converted the entire Roman Empire.

This huge conversion, not only helped in “validating” Christianity, it helped also in validating  Judaism as its ancestor religion.

Later came Islam and helped “validating” even more, but it was really Constantine the great that gave the big boost.

Constantine’s move and the “validations” of Christianity and Islam had probably an influences on Judaism as a religion and as a culture ?

I am searching for any kinds of references that discuss the matter or that may describe some differences pre and post Constantine the Great’s forced conversion to Christianity?

Comment: Hi Isaac and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Your question, while interesting, requests opinion-based answers, which is not what this site is for. I recommend you read the rules [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help) and I hope you stick around.

Comment: @Harel13, I am not so sure why do you assume that it is an opinion related question. I am pretty sure that there are some studies made in regards to the shift in religion  and culture  post Constantine the Great? However I respect your decision.

Comment: @Harel 13 it might not be a religious Halacha question but it is a valid question in regards to Judaism ?

Comment: @Harel 13 I am Jewish myself, and for me Judaism is not only a religion, it’s also history and culture and so much more. I thought that is forum is for academic studies. I guess that this forum specifically is just Halacha answers by orthodox rabbis

Comment: No Isaac, there's plenty of room here for non-Halachic questions. In fact, even the halachic questions here are hypothetical. The site directs people to ask real questions, הלכה למעשה, to real rabbis (CYLOR, as they say). The reason I voted your question be closed is because you wrote at the end: "in what ways do *you think*". What I think, or what anyone else here thinks, means you're requesting our opinions. You may rephrase your question to request a different kind of answer, something sourced, preferably, and request it be re-opened, though.

Comment: @Harel 13, also my question in the title has the ring of an opinion related question, but as you can see I was really just asking for references, and possible  influences (that can be measured by comparing pre and post)

Comment: As for Judaism not being a religion, I highly agree with you. But when this site was set up, it was decided to allow only certain types of questions here. It's not my call. Anyway, I still hope you'll stick around. :) And if you want, there's another such site that may allow a wider variety of questions, which is judaism.codidact.com.

Comment: Great! If you're looking for references, then edit your question to clarify and we'll vote to re-open, if it's alright with other site guidelines.

Comment: Your premise is wrong, Judaism was one of the largest religions in the Roman Empire around the 1st–2nd centuries CE. Some historians claim that even 10% could have been the share of Jews in the total population.